# Amending scope values in token request causes problems accessing APIs afterwards

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I am encountering the following error after amending a scope value being sent in the headers of a token POST request against the token API endpoint for our WSO2 instance:

```
ERRORS.900901

Invalid CredentialsAccess failure for API: /scheme/v1, version: v1 with key: fa41109938522762bcca953336f0e0e2. 

Make sure your have given the correct access token
```

This error comes after I successfully get a token returned and then use that token for a an API setup in WSO2 publisher. This particular endpoint in the error does not actually have any scopes applied to it which causes me some confusion about why this error comes up since its not a scope protected endpoint so my token shouldn't matter?

This happened after I realised there was a typo in a scope value I was sending in the POST request and so I updated it accordingly.

If I leave the typo in I can use the token generated for a subsequent API request and dont get this error.

Am I right in thinking that tokens are generated based on the list of scopes returned back by the Token API for the given user?

I have tried manually revoking the access token using a cURL command as documented [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Token+API#TokenAPI-Revokingaccesstokens) and generating a new one using the corrected scope names, but still this error comes back after trying to access that API.

What could be the issue here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This error comes after I successfully get a token returned and then
>   use that token for a an API setup in WSO2 publisher. This particular
>   endpoint in the error does not actually have any scopes applied to it
>   which causes me some confusion about why this error comes up since its
>   not a scope protected endpoint so my token shouldn't matter?

This also can happen if there were any errors while validating the token. This doesn't look like a scope issue. So if you can provide the corresponding logs in `wso2carbon.log`, I can tell the exact reason.

> Am I right in thinking that tokens are generated based on the list of
>   scopes returned back by the Token API for the given user?

Yes.